# how to link my database item to php?

Tags: php

i'm currently stuck because i have no idea hot to insert my database item to be displayed on my php. Need help. Im a php beginner.

database

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","account");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM product";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
?>
```

index.php

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo $row['product_img_name']; ?>" alt="">
<div class="add-to-cart">
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to cart"></a>
</div>
<div class="caption">
<h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $row['price'];?></h4>
<h4><a href="product.html"><?php echo $row['product_name'];?></a></h4>
<p><?php echo $row['product_desc'];?></p>   
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Too general.  Show some database details and related codes

Comment: May I suggest that you try some tutorial on the subject to get some basic idea how to do this. We'll be happy to help you out with specific problems, but you should make some effort yourself.

Comment: @sinaza this is the database detail

Comment: @henrikstroem i did read through sql and php link throughout the day and still stuck with understanding on how to actually link the data in database to my bootstrap page.

Comment: First of all, note that mysql and mysqli methods are different. You have used one to connect and the other to get data. Second point is you have to use `query` before trying to fetch data. Take a look at http://codular.com/php-mysqli I promise you will be fine :)

Comment: @sinaza thank you sooooooo much! i did it !  hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I´m assuming that you DID a query to database before run this code. 
In this case, the code is ok but it only displays one item, isn´t it?.

If you need to display more than one, just add a for or while structure to diplay all of them

I hope it fits for you.